# If and elseif's not working

Tags: php

Sorry for the messy code but basically this code will only ever make `$booktype = "ICT"` and if I remove the "else" from elseif, it makes it equal `ENGLISH`.

Whats going wrong?

I've echoed POST_ Book room and that comes out fine.

```
if ($_POST['bookroom'] == "142" || "040" || "139"|| "104") {
    $booktype = "ICT";
} elseif ($_POST['bookroom'] == "015" || "016" || "017" || "018" || "027" || "028") {
    $booktype = "MATHS";
} elseif ($_POST['bookroom'] == "E03") {
    $booktype = "MUSIC";
} elseif ($_POST['bookroom'] == "202" || "204" || "205" || "206" || "207") {
    $booktype = "ENGLISH";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of the day, you're not using 'or' correctly. To shorten your code, you can do your if-statement like this:

```
if(in_array($_POST['bookroom'], array("142","040","139","104"))) {
```

To properly use an "or" or "and" clause, you'd need to make the statement self-contained. That is,

```
if(this option is true || this option is true || this option is true)
if($a == 4 || $a == 5 || $a == 6)
```

Comment: Although I am receiving syntax errors with your answer :\

Comment: @user3586863 There is a closing bracket missing in first `if` statement.

Comment: @Linek I added that but its still giving me an error. Like it doesn't want the if statement to end.

Comment: @user3586863 - I just updated my answer to include the missing closing parenthesis. Check to make sure you've got the other closing parenthesis in the correct spot

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain conditions like this. Change it to

```
$_POST['bookroom'] == "142" || $_POST['bookroom'] == "040" || [...]
```

Also, using a [switch case](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) with fall-throughs would be more readable here.

Comment: `in_array($_POST['bookroom'], array('my', 'values'))` would make much more sense.

Comment: Do NOT use switch. It is an overkill and bad solution in general. Use `in_array` instead as one of the answers states.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change it to use in_array function:

From:

```
if ($_POST['bookroom'] == "142" || "040" || "139"|| "104"){
```

to

```
if (in_array($_POST['bookroom'], array("142","040","139","104"))){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch !

```
switch($_POST['bookroom']){

case "142":
...
break;

case "040":
...
break;

}
```

Comment: Don't use switch! It is messy, hard to read, a bad solution in general. Especially in this particular very simple problem that is solvable with `in_array` function.

Comment: @Linek Why switch is bad solution О_о?!

Comment: Generally, switch is not bad as a concept but it is bad to use in this particular example. Try go Google "Why is switch bad" and you will find links like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417070/switch-statements-are-bad Should answer a couple of questions.