# Refactoring Large Switch Statement

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates, switch-statement

I did look at the following question 
[How to refactor this huge switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926518/how-to-refactor-this-huge-switch-statement)

I am refactoring a code which has a huge switch statement in the Page_Load event handler of an aspx page.

The code is something like this

```
string switchValue = GetSwitchValue();     

switch(switchValue) 
{   
 case "switchValue1" : 
       stopwatch.Restart();
       HandlerForSwitchValue1();
       stopwatch.Stop();
       LogDetails();
       break;
 case "Foo" : 
       stopwatch.Restart();
       HandlerForFoo();
       stopwatch.Stop();
       LogDetails();
       break;
 ... 
 ... 
 ...
 }
```

I plan to create another class say 'Handlers' which would contain a Dictionary of string and the Action delegate.

```
IDictionary<string, Action> actionMaps = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
```

my question is, where do I populate the dictionary? If I populate it in the 'Handlers' class, how do I access the Private handler methods defined in the aspx code behind?

The other option is to populate the Dictionary in the code behind. something like this

```
Handlers.Add("SwitchValue1", HandlerForSwitchValue1);
```

The Add method or whatever I name it would add the items to the dictionary in the 'Handler's class.

Now I will have 100 lines which would look something like this. Again what do I get out of this?

```
Handlers.Add("SwitchValue2", HandlerForSwitchValue2);
```

Comment: Note, that the compiler creates such a mapping for you. The C# compiler has special handing for switch statements operating on strings. It creates a dictionary under the covers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the mapping changes at runtime, you can create a `static readonly` Dictionary as a field of a class and initialize that field from the constructor of that class.

If you want the mapping to be dynamic at runtime, you can instead use a `static` property in a class.  The backing store for that property could also be initialized in the class constructor.

Comment: @Eric.. The mappings are static. So you are advising me to create the Dictionary in the other class. But how do I access the private handlers defined in the code behind? Please advise if I understand your suggestion correctly.

Comment: @Yogendra: It has been a while since I worked with aspx, but you should be able to add the static field/property to the code behind file.