# Best design pattern to write a categorizer?

Tags: design-patterns

My categorizer was very simple.

```
categorize(life) {
   if (life.heart) 
      return animal
   else
      return plant
}
```

Then life grew complicated and more checks were added

```
categorize(life) {
   if (life.heart) 
       if (life.onland)
          return landanimal;
       else
          return wateranimal;
   else
      if (life.land )
         return landplant
      else
         return treeplant
}
```

But stuff did not end there, soon animals became reptiles, mammals, etc. and if-else began to clutter.

What design pattern is suggested to work around this nested if-else complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very much like the famous binary decision tree solution to the 20 questions problem.  One way of representing your algorithm as data would be to build a binary tree where each node contains a function (or a Strategy instance, same-same) deciding whether to go left or right in the tree.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/505608/58668) to a somewhat related problem may also be of interest to you.