# Using Polymorphism instead of Switch

Tags: oop

Here is the logic:
The server prepares the file (like index.html, or some.pdf) that it is going to send through HTTP response. Based on the suffix I wanna set the Content-type in HTTP header.

The logic now is I have Class Filetype, with lots of specific filetype subclasses extending it. But still I need to use "switch" to identify the suffix. Something like:

```
Filetype f = null;
if(suffix == "pdf"){
    f = Filetype_pdf(source);
} else if (suffix == "html") {
    f = Filetype_text(source);
}
```

But I use inheritance just to avoid these "if"s. Any advice to this issue or is this the way it should be? Thanks.

Comment: The inheritance will save you from `if`s when you're actually using `Filetype` instance. At some point you still need a way to check how to instantiate proper `Diletype` derived class. Often that task is delegated to something called a factory (either a factory  method or a factory class) and this one still uses some kind of logic (`if` statements or `switch`) to create proper instance. Search for factory pattern to learn more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large Switch statements: Bad OOP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505454/large-switch-statements-bad-oop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have the following hierarchy:

```
Filetype
    HTMLType
    PDFType
    TxtType
```

Now assume that each of these classes understands the `type` message (not their instances, the class). Then you can create a class method in `Filetype` namely `classFor` that receives one argument `extension` and responds the subclass of `Filetype` that handles that `extension`. The implementation of `classFor` consists in enumerating all the subclasses looking for the subclass whose `type` matches `extension`.

In Smalltalk this would look like

```
classFor: extension
    ^Filetype allSubclasses detect: [:cls | cls type = extension]
```

Of course, there is an `if` message somewhere in the implementation of `detect`, but your code does not see it and elegantly expresses the condition that must be met.

**EDIT:**

The beauty if this approach is that the method `classFor` that detects the appropriate subclass will not change if you add (or remove) other subclasses that support new types of files. This contrasts with the `switch` statement that must name all the possibilities exhaustively. By avoiding the `switch` your code acquires the generality required to keep working with newer versions of your hierarchy.